# CsvHelper - how to always serialize enums as values

Tags: c#, csvhelper

I'm using the great .NET library 'CsvHelper' to output CSV's from my C# application. I found that enums are serialized as its string value rather than the underlying value. I figured I'd write my own TypeConverter to do this or me, as shown below

```
public class EnumConverter : ITypeConverter
{
    public object ConvertFromString(string text, IReaderRow row, MemberMapData memberMapData)
    {
        if (text == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(text));

        if (memberMapData == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(memberMapData));

        var type = memberMapData.Member.GetType();
        if (!type.IsEnum)
            throw new InvalidOperationException($"Cannot use EnumConverter for non enum type '{type.Name}'");

        var underlyingType = Enum.GetUnderlyingType(type);

        object enumValue;
        try
        {
            enumValue = Convert.ChangeType(text, underlyingType);
        }
        catch (Exception x)
        {
            throw new FormatException($"Invalid '{type.Name}' value '{text}' - cannot convert to {underlyingType.Name}");
        }

        if (!Enum.IsDefined(type, enumValue))
            throw new FormatException($"Invalid '{type.Name}' value '{text}'");

        return Enum.ToObject(type, enumValue);
    }


    public string ConvertToString(object value, IWriterRow row, MemberMapData memberMapData)
    {
        if (value == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(value));

        var type = value.GetType();
        if (!type.IsEnum)
            throw new InvalidOperationException($"Cannot use EnumConverter for non enum type '{type.Name}'");

        var underlyingType = Enum.GetUnderlyingType(value.GetType());

        try
        {
            return Convert.ChangeType(value, underlyingType).ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception x)
        {
            throw new FormatException($"Cannot convert enum '{type.Name}' to {underlyingType.Name}");
        }
    }
}
```

This works great if I specify the converter to use as an attribute my model

```
 [CsvHelper.Configuration.Attributes.TypeConverter(typeof(Converters.EnumConverter))]
    public TestEnum Field { get; set; }
```

What doesn't work if I add it a converter to the CsvWriter/CsvReader configuration as below

```
csv.Configuration.TypeConverterCache.RemoveConverter<Enum>();
csv.Configuration.TypeConverterCache.AddConverter<Enum>(new Converters.EnumConverter());
```

I imagine this is because I'm using the generic Enum instead of the actual enum type (TestEnum) - however, I really don't want to have to specify this for every enum in the system I'll be writing. is there a way to get this working for *every* enum?

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the `enum` you want. Specifying `Enum` is like specifying `Object` instead of a specific `class`.

```
csv.Configuration.TypeConverterCache.AddConverter<TestEnum>(new Converters.EnumConverter());
```

I think it's possible to do what you though. Add a feature request on github for this.

Comment: is it possible now?